# Call and pass parameter to method in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created this small project to show what I want to do, but in reality it will be used in a large application which uses about 60 different threads.

I have two classes

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Http http = new Http();
        Thread threadHttp = new Thread(http, "httpThread1");
        threadHttp.start();

        http.getPage("http://google.com"); // <-- This gets called on 
                                           // the main thread, 
                                           //I want it to get called from the
                                            // "httpThread1" thread
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Http implements Runnable {
    volatile OkHttpClient client;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).retryOnConnectionFailure(true).build();

    }

    public void getPage(String url) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

From the main thread, I want to be able to call the `getPage` method but have it execute on the `httpThread1` that we started and initialized `OkHttpClient client`

Is this possible? how can it be done?

Comment: What's the problem with `updater.test(someVar)`?

Comment: `updater.test`?

Comment: wouldn't  test run on the main thread though? not the new thread I started for updater?

Comment: @Arya Your last sentence says `How can I call test from the main thread ...`

Comment: @ernest_k yes, but I want the method to run on the new method that we started for updater

Comment: @Arya It's a bit unclear. Why not pass `var` the same way you pass `new Date()` to the constructor and call `test` from within the `run()` method? If the `var` value is only known to the main thread after `threadUpdater` has started, then you might want to use things like callbacks...

Comment: I will edit this with more clarity.  I'm working on it

Comment: "the method to run on the new method" - Its a bit unclear like @ernest_k said. Why do you need to make another thread anyways?

Comment: I have updated the question. Should be clear now

Comment: @Arya I think you're using the `run` method for the wrong thing. You should be doing in `run` what you're currently doing in `getPage`

Comment: I understand I can do that in this example. But I need this for a much bigger project and after initialization, there are times that a different thread needs to call and pass a parameter to another thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runnable#run` is the method designed to do the actual work of a `Runnable` object. So you would have to make it do what you're currently doing in `getPage`.

You can use state to store `url`, and save the response in a different field. See further comments about how you can refactor this to simplify it even further. But from the current code, the simplest changes could be:

```
class Http implements Runnable {

    //initialize Http. This can be done better perhaps
    volatile OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true).build();

    private Response response;

    private String url;

    public Http(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.getPage(this.url);
    }

    public void getPage(String url) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        try {
            this.response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `main` method:

```
Http http = new Http("http://google.com");
Thread threadHttp = new Thread(http, "httpThread1");
threadHttp.start();
threadHttp.join();
Response resp = http.getResponse();
```

---

However, this can be substantially simplified with the use of futures. For example, it could look as simple as:

```
class Http {
    volatile OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true).build();

    public Response getPage(String url) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        try {
            this.response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And, using futures, your main method can look even simpler:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Http http = new Http();
    CompletableFuture<Response> future = 
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> http.getPage("http://google.com"));

    //the preceding statement will call `getPage` on a different thread.
    //So you can do other things before blocking with next statement

    Response resp = future.join();
}
```

You can even use a thread pool with `supplyAsync` if you need more control over how asynchronous tasks run.

Comment: The futures example is very interesting. I'm going to see if I can use that in the main project

Comment: In the Main class I'm getting a red line under `.supplyAsync(()` with error "The method supplyAsync(Supplier<U>) in the type CompletableFuture is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {})"

Comment: Is `getPage` a `void` method in your version of `Http`?

Comment: @Arya If you prefer, you can keep it void (maybe you want to retrieve the response with a getter). If it's void, you'd have to use `CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> http.get...`

Comment: @ernest_k Will this example work if the user wants to supply a new URL for each thread? In your code, once you set the URL, each thread will call on that URL. What if the user wants to supply a custom URL to each thread using the same Http object?

Comment: @PrashantPandey That's why I suggested the second approach. It doesn't hold state for any particular request. So the `Http` object can be resused as many times as desired (assuming `OkHttpClient` is thread-safe). It's just important to note that `runAsync` and `supplyAsync` use the fork-join pool. If more threads are needed, then one should use a custom thread pool

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `test` method within the `Updater` class like this: `updater.test(yourVarHere)`
To call a method within a separate thread see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489549/8891686)
You might also want to check out the [Java concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I think that you might do this:

```
class HttpThread extends Thread {
     volatile OkHttpClient client;

     HttpThread(Runnable target, String name) {
        super(target, name);
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).retryOnConnectionFailure(true).build();
     }

     public void getPage(String url) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

And in Main class:

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Thread httpThread = new HttpThread(http, "httpThread1");
       httpThread.start();
       httpThread.getPage("http://google.com"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this but unfortunately I can't use it since in my main project I have to use the `Runnable` method as the class is already extending another class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871073/java-thread-vs-runnable It's the almost same https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: In the main project I have `public class OkHttp extends WebSocketListener implements Runnable` I have to do `extends WebSocketListener` not sure how I can use your example